# Dynamic Div Id Get From Route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to get the id of  from the route.queryparams?
I have done this in vue js

```
 <div id="{{this.$route.query.data}}" class="col-md-12>{{data}}</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Arguments) directive, or `:` for short, also [no mustache for attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes) in Vue 2:

```
<div :id="this.$route.query.data" class="col-md-12>{{data}}</div>
```